# How are the number of blocks for different classes in classful addressing determined in IPv4?

Tags: networking, binary, ipv4

The following are the initial bits (out of 32) for the different classes of addresses in IPv4:
[image]

and the following are the number of blocks and block sizes respectively for each class:
[image]

For class A, I can see that the number of blocks is **2^7=128**, and block size is **2^24=16777216**. But I am unable to understand the following:

- How the number of blocks in class B (16384), and in  class C (2097152) are calculated.
- How the size of blocks for classes D and E are calculated.
- How can class D and class E have the same number of blocks and block size even though their initial four bits are not the same?

Please help me understand it as the calculation I used for class A is not working out for these.

Comment: Classful networking is dead, killed in 1993 by RFCs 1518 and 1519. Please let it rest in peace. Modern networking and network devices do no use classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keep in mind: you have 32 bits overall.

Class A uses **one** bit of those 32; so 31 are **left**. And guess what ... 2^**7** and 2^**24** results in ... 31 bits left for block data.

Classes D and E ... both using **four** bits; so 28 bits are left. 
2^28 is ... surprise 268.435.456

Now just go and check how many bits are left for the other classes!

The thing is: those first bits are mutually exclusive.

When the 32 bits start with 0, you know: class A; and so on.

Answer (score 1):

netid = number of blocks
hostid = block size

IP address has total of 4 bytes and is divided into 5 classes depending on the initial bit(s).

In class A, one byte define the netid and 3 bytes defines the hostid.
In class B, two bytes define the netid and 2 bytes defines the hostid.
In class C, three bytes define the netid and 1 byte defines the hostid.
Hence;
for A
number of blocks = 2^7 as 1 bit is reserved for class identification. (0)
block size = 2^24
for B
number of blocks = 2^14 as 2 bits are reserved for class identification. (10)
block size = 2^16
for C
number of blocks = 2^21 as 3 bits are reserved for class identification. (110)
block size = 2^8

The system of netid and blockid is not applicable to class D and class E.

Comment: Network classes _were_ defined (before they were deprecated in 1993, over 20 years ago) by the first few bits of the address. Network classes no longer exist, and modern networking doesn't use network classes, which were replaced by CIDR (_Classless_ Inter-Domain Routing) using VLSM. Classes had to be eliminated before the Internet went commercial in 1995.

Answer (score 0):

since it is of class B - first two byte are fixed.
and first  bits of each block is not used (16-2).
so  number of blocks are 2^14 =16384 and block size is no host id i.e=2^16=65535
similarly for class c
no. of blocks 2^(24-3)=2097152 and block size 2^8=256

Answer (score 0):

Class A contains first byte of net id (255.0.0.0) and has a range 0-127 equals 128(127-0 +1).So total no blocks= 128.

Similarly
Class B contains 2 bytes of net it(255.255.0.0) and has a range 128-191 equals 64(191-128 +1).So total no of blocks= 64 * 255 (of 2nd byte) = 16,384.

And
Class C contains 3 bytes of net id(255.255.255.0) and range 192-223 equals 32(223-192 +1).So total no of blocks = 32 * 255 (of 2nd byte) * 255 (of 3rd byte)= 2,097,152

Class D is assigned block=1 (since it uses multicast addresses instead of uni-cast).

Class E is assigned block=1 (because no partitioning into block and hosts as reserved for future use).

Comment: Network classes have not been used in this century, having been deprecated in 1993, 26 years ago! That was two years before the Internet went commercial in 1995.

Answer (score 0):

In IPv4 addressing, the IP address is 32 bits long. 
The first n bits, which are all 1s are known as network bits 
The remaining 32-n bits which are all 0s are known as host bits. 
Further for each class, there is a fixed prefix which is found in each address belonging to that class, 
Class A: 0 
Class B: 10 
Class C: 110 
Class D: 1110 
Class E: 1111 
Host Bits for each class are 
Class A: 8 
Class B: 16 
Class C: 24 
Class D: 32 
Class E: 32
For calculating the number of blocks and block sizes, the following formula can be used, 
**Number of Blocks =  2^(number of Hostbits- length of prefix)** 
**Block Size  =  2^(32- number of Hostbits)** 
*Class D & E are exceptions to this, you could just remember their values*